# Replacing default 'ship.scn' scene with blender object crashing app

Tags: scenekit, blender, collada

I am trying to add an object from Blender into the default AR project in xcode.

I export my object from Blnder as a .dae and convert to .scn inside of xcode (editor

I then replace the default "art.scnassets/ship.scn" scene with my imported file name (art.scnassets/monkey.scn). When I try to run the app I get a "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optioinal value." What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Did you do any other changes or did you only replace the asset? It would also help if you included the line you're seeing that error on, even if you didn't modify it.

Comment: The only thing I did was replace the asset; none of the other code changed. The error came when it got to the file name line that I swapped out.

Answer (score 0):

There's not all that much to go by in your question, but I'm guessing that  – since you say that you replaced the asset and didn't change any of the code – that the project is crashing because the code that loads the scene is still looking for a file with the old "ship" name which is no longer in the project. In which case the code would fail to load the file, returning `nil` which then when force unwrapped results in that error you're seeing.

To solve that problem: ensure that the code that loads the scene is using the name of the new asset.